# I have already add an obj model in threejs. How to remove it?

Tags: three.js, loader

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

    var object = event.content;
    object.position.z = -700;
    scene.add( object );    
});

loader.load( 'obj/male02/male02.obj', 'obj/male02/male02.mtl' );
```

how to remove the object?

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the object you have just added?

Answer (score 0):

You just scene.remove (object);